# gRPC client-side load-balancing

Tags: kubernetes, grpc-go

I have a headless service running with multiple replicas. When trying to verify client-side load balancing using round robin I see that all requests end up in the same replica.
Client setup looks like following:

```
 conn, err := grpc.Dial(
        address,
        grpc.WithInsecure(),
        grpc.WithDefaultServiceConfig(`{"loadBalancingPolicy":"round_robin"}`),)
```

I've verified multiple endpoints in service. I also verified that service resolves to these multiple IP, but somehow it does connect only to the first pod in that list.
`MAX_CONNECTION_AGE` is set to 30s on the server side to ensure client re-connects occasionally in case there has been a scale-up.
I've followed numerous articles on how to set this up and it just does not work. What am I missing?

Comment: [Here's article](https://kubernetes.io/blog/2018/11/07/grpc-load-balancing-on-kubernetes-without-tears/) about gRPC load balancing in k8s

Comment: Thanks, I read this article as well. We would like not to use any proxy and keep only a client-side load-balancing at the moment

Answer (score 2):

The key was to explicitly use `dns:///` as a prefix to target. Despite the fact it is stated as a default in documentation.